# Github not showing files in the repository

Tags: git, github, version-control

[image]

I am seeing following screen instead of files in my repository.

Comment: Questions: Had there been files showing up within Github, and then they disappeared? Are you certain that you had pushed the commits to GitHub?

Comment: Yes .. I pushed one file to repo.

Comment: https://github.com/ranesiddhesh1511/ToolPathGenerator Your repository is empty.

Comment: Alright, run these two commands and update your answer with the results: `git remote -v` and `git status`

Comment: Is there any way to create and push file in browser , just for checking?

Comment: 'siddhesh@siddhesh-Inspiron-3543:~/Git/ToolPathGenerator$ git remote -v
origin https://github.com/ranesiddhesh1511/ToolPathGenerator (fetch)
origin https://github.com/ranesiddhesh1511/ToolPathGenerator (push)
siddhesh@siddhesh-Inspiron-3543:~/Git/ToolPathGenerator$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is based on 'origin/master', but the upstream is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)

nothing to commit, working directory clean'

Comment: @ChrisForrence : ^ This is what I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you had left off the ".git" at the end of your remote creation commands, hence the missing upstream. Run the following in your repository root to fix your remotes:

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin https://github.com/ranesiddhesh1511/ToolPathGenerator.git
git push origin master
```